# Ionic state controller doesn't execute after $state.go

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, controller

I'm experiencing some issues with ionic and it's state functionality.

Basically, I'm retrieving some data from a distant server, which I display in a view/state.

If the user clicks on one of the elements I display it calls a scope function that changes the `$state` via a `$state.go('other_view',{params})` call.
Until here no problems, the thing is when it does change state, the controller assigned to the state doesn't execute, can't even get it to display a simple `console.log("hello")`.

Here's a simple illustration of what I'm experiencing.

```
var incaRooms = angular.module('inca.rooms', ['ionic','ui.router', 'cb.x2js','ngSanitize'])


// ----------------------------
// config for the app (routing)
// ----------------------------



.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('rooms',{
            url: '/rooms',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/rooms/rooms.html',
            controller : controllers.roomsController,
            resolve : {
                // data loading
                jsonData : function($http) {
                  return $http.get("assets/data.xml")
                  .then(function (data) { // promise

                    var x2js = new X2JS();
                    jsonData = x2js.xml_str2json(data.data);

                    return jsonData;
                  });
                }
            },
            cache : false
        });
});

/////////////////
// CONTROLLERS //
/////////////////

var controllers = {};

// rooms
controllers.roomsController = roomsController;
incaRooms.controller('getters', controllers.roomsController);


///////////////////////
// GENERAL FUNCTIONS //
///////////////////////

function getUnit(jsonresult,unit_id){
  var infoUnit = jsonresult.UNIT_LIST.UNIT;
  return infoUnit;
}


/////////////////
// CONTROLLERS //
/////////////////

function roomsController($scope,$state, $ionicHistory, $ionicPopup, $ionicScrollDelegate,$ionicLoading, jsonData){

  var unit = getUnit(jsonData,0);
  $scope.unit = unit;


  $scope.selectRoom = function(index){
  $state.go('patients',{'indexRoom' : index, 'jsonData' :  JSON.stringify(jsonData)});
  }



}
```

This state/view leads to another very similar one, this next state/view's controller doesn't execute once loaded.

```
var incaPatients = angular.module('inca.patients', ['ionic','ui.router', 'cb.x2js','ngSanitize'])


// ----------------------------
// config for the app (routing)
// ----------------------------

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('patients',{
            url: '/patients/{indexRoom}{jsonData}',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/patients/patients.html',
            controller : controllers.patientsController,
            cache : false
        });
});

/////////////////
// CONTROLLERS //
/////////////////

var controllers = {};

// patients
controllers.patientsController = patientsController;
incaPatients.controller('getters', controllers.patientsController);


///////////////////////
// GENERAL FUNCTIONS //
///////////////////////

function getRoom(jsonresult,unit_id,room_id){
  var infoPatient = jsonresult.UNIT_LIST.UNIT.ROOM[room_id];
  return infoPatient;
}


/////////////////
// CONTROLLERS //
/////////////////

function patientsController($scope,$state, $ionicHistory, $ionicPopup, $ionicScrollDelegate,$ionicLoading){

  var jsonData = JSON.parse($state.params.jsonData);
  var indexRoom = $state.params.indexRoom;
  console.log("hello");
}
```

Any clue on why the `console.log()` isn't executed?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. but I fixed it by set *cache-view* attribute of *ion-view* element to *false*.

```
<ion-view title="View Title" ng-controller="someCtrl" cache-view="false">
    ...
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've finally figured out what was the problem.
It seems that you can't put a single controller into this controllers variables I created. Or at least that makes it unknown from the stateProvider.

I simply called the function patientsController instead of controllers.patientsController and it worked fine !
Anyway this variable wasn't useful anymore as I only have one controller for those states.